# Restore windows server backup of system partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

How do this ?? It has to be done when the windows is not running, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows OS Install disc.  Select the option to repair your computer, then tell it to restore from a different backup.  See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755163.aspx